In python, how to deal with relative path change when changing the working directory
I know we can use absolute path to deal with the problem, but I wonder if there is a better way, especially when we consider distributing the code
Here's the problem in detail
Project structure
/a
  utils.py (under directory a)
        /b/b.json
        /c/c.ipynb

Correspondingly, this is the screenshot of an actual problem in pycharm. Notice utils.py is under directory a

In a.py utils.py, it has a line tmp = open("./b/b.json", "r")
In c.ipynb, it has a line import utils.py import utils (This line works since pycharm ads /a into the system path)
However, if I run import utils in c.ipynb, I had an error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ./b/b.json

I understand this is expected, cause the current working directory is /a/c, not /a. So when resolving the relative path in a.py utils.py, it will become /a/c/b/b.json. But is there a more elegant way, rather than setting a global variable like PROJECT_ROOT to deal with the problem? (__file__ doesn't work in this case because it's jupyter notebook.)
And in general, what is the best practice for developing projects and handling relative imports, especially when dealing with jupyter notebooks (My current understanding is modifying the PYTHONPATH for relative imports, but again, what about file reading problem?)

Does the provided answer fixes the problem or is there a modification required? If it answers your problem, please consider selecting it as accepted, or request for the desired results in comments.

I would argue that setting a global variable as you suggested will be the way to go, because Jupyter Notebook will only look into the current directory for ordinarily created package/library/module imports (especially something as simple as another Python file).[1]


I understand this is expected, cause the current working directory of is /a/c, not /a. So when resolving the relative path in a.py, it will become /a/c/b/b.json.

We have to use dynamic absolute imports in files outside the notebook's directory and then append with /. or /.. as required to make it accessible by the notebook. Then manually add the external directories to sys path within your notebook (this was the technique suggested in this answer).


But is there a more elegant way [...]?

Elegance in this context is subjective, but pathlib.Path and os.path() are your (best) friends in this scenario.

Lastly, the way I have structured my notebook(s) professionally is to always place folders and directories I want to import from, within the same level as the notebook. As long as they are well-organized, it is better this way than placing them outside the notebook's directory.


Proposed Solution
Since you have not provided a minimal code sample, I have setup my experiment as follows:


utils.py will house a simple arithmetic function which we will attempt to import within c.ipynb. It will also contain a function that prints the contents of b.json.

# \a -> utils.py

import os
import json
from pathlib import Path


def add_mult(x, y, z):
    return x * y + z

def print_json():
    # Relative path; Mr. Jupyter hates this so don't do it
    # json_file = open("./b/b.json", 'r')

    # Absolute JSON file path
    json_file_path = Path(os.getcwd() + "/.././/b/b.json").__str__()
    json_file = open(json_file_path, 'r')
    json_object = json.load(json_file)

    return json.dumps(json_object, indent=1)


b.json will contain some simple texts as seen on JSON.org (or simply makeup yours).

Then in c.ipynb, we have:


# \a\c -> c.ipynb

import sys, os

# From \c, step out to \a, step out yet again outside \a
import_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("..\.."))

# Add the obtained parent path to sys path to force-expose \a contents
if import_path not in sys.path: sys.path.append(import_path + "\\")

# Import away
from a.utils import add_mult, print_json

# 1 * 2 + 3
ans = add_mult(1, 2, 3)
print(ans)

# Print formatted contents of \a\b\b.json
json_text = print_json()
print(json_text)

Output:

